# Allign the dynamic data in Webview android application

Tags: android, webview

I have a query. I get posts from Facebook as HTML tags. I display this data in a web view. But there are few problems related to alignment of text of the feeds. These feeds are not properly aligned in web view. Can i align these data. If possible please tell me how can i achieve it.

Any help will be a great help for me.

Thanks.

Comment: hey how are you displaying HTML dynamically in webview everty time you receive new HTML tags from facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set following for your WebView that will adjust your text/imgaes  in your WebView.

```
 webview.setInitialScale(1);
```

Comment: Fine. Thanks for the response. But I have already used this webview.setInitialScale(100);. I need to allign the data i get from web service in webview. Thats what i am working on. Any help.